# Lato font rendering issue on Debian gnome3

Tags: linux, fonts, debian

I tried to fix font rendering on my Debian 8 computer and with [this](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=88545) instructions (http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=88545) i installed infinality. So it helped and now I get much smoother fonts but there is one big problem, font named Lato is completely broken. Look.

[image]
[image]

This is not a big problem, but this font is used literally everywhere in the web. And this problem not only in firefox, but in whole system. How to fix it? Or I should remove infinality?

Comment: All right, its going insane. I found more web fonts with same issue on my pc so I just completely remove infinality and restart X. This one helped.
So, what now? Do I need to delete this post or answer it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

infinality is designed to mimick a very specific font rendering found on windows systems. Because MS developed this rendering with a specific font set, it does not work on any random font, since it is designed to hide bugs in windows fonts and windows fonts are designed to hide bugs in windows rendering (that's the problem when you develop code and fonts at the same time).

The default Linux rendering is much more font-agnostic but it is anathema to anyone coming from Windows or OSX (for radically different reasons).

It is useless to explain to any user that the text rendering he is used to is not the alpha et omega, and there are enough ex-windows people they've pushed infinality to the top of the charts